# Inputdlg in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a figure window on MATLAB. I want the user to type in his answer on that figure window. The code I am using is :

```
> prompt = {'Your Age: '}
> dlg_title = 'Bio data'
> answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title)'
```

This is the figure which I am getting.

[image]

My Questions :

1) How to make the age, which I type in this dialogue box, appear up at a specific position ON my figure window once I click on "ok" button of this dialogue box.

2) How to put up a customized background on this dialogue box.

3) How to get the user input ON the figure window without the dialogue box. like shown in the picture given bellow : (so that answer is typed on the horizontal line and vertical line is the cursor)

[image]

Comment: you are looking for a [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) of style `'edit'`.

Comment: Have you tried using [`guide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-guide-gui-example.html) tool for building your GUI in Matlab?

Comment: @Shai , i know about the uicontrol but that contains push buttons and sliders and other things. Taking the user input in form of a string, written by the user itself, will still be the work of inputdlg isnt it ?

Comment: 1. if you want customization and embedding in a larger GUI than dialogue box is quite limited. 2. `uicontrol` of stype `'edit'` allows the user to enter free text like in dialogue.

Comment: To expand upon Shai's answer: after the input from the user becomes available, you change the string of your placeholder `uicontrol` to the number.... Something like: `set(txt_age,'String',inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be close to what you want,

```
function age = AgeDB()
f = figure;
set(f,'Position',[200 350 350 150],'Color',[.4 .6 .4],'MenuBar','none',...
    'Name','Bio data','Visible','off');
bc = [.4 .6 .4];
ht = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[30 80 160 40],...
    'String','Your Age:','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold',...
    'BackgroundColor',bc,'ForegroundColor','w');
he = uicontrol('style','edit','Position', [200 80 120 40],...
    'BackgroundColor',bc,'FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold',...
    'ForegroundColor','w','Callback',{@Age_Callback});
hp = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Ok',...
    'Position', [150 10 50 20],...
    'Callback', 'close'); 
movegui(f,'center')
set(f,'Visible','on')
waitfor(he)

    function Age_Callback(hObject,eventdata)
         age = str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
    end
end
```

[image]